# How to do complex document from three tables in json to mongodb using Pentaho

Tags: json, mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have three tables in one database.
These tables have a foreign key between they.
The Table1 is master from Table2 and Table 2 is master from Table3.

I want get data values and transform in MongoDB document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("cf3977abf592d19962ff7982"),
    "T1Column1" : "Lorem Ipsum",
    "T1Column2" : ISODate("2015-11-27T16:04:24.000Z"),
    "Table2" : [ 
        {
            "T2Column1" : NumberLong(1),
            "T2Column2" : "Lorem Ipsum",
            "Table3" : [ 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Lorem Ipsum",
                    "T3Column2" : "Lorem Ipsum"
                }, 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Lorem Ipsum",
                    "T3Column2" : "Lorem Ipsum"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "T2Column1" : NumberLong(2),
            "T2Column2" : "Lorem Ipsum",
            "Table3" : [ 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Lorem Ipsum1",
                    "T3Column2" : "Lorem Ipsum"
                }, 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Lorem Ipsum2",
                    "T3Column2" : "Lorem Ipsum"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I already try to use "Mongo document path" in MongoDB Output Step, but don't is possible use "upsert" for subdocuments, as we can see in [MongoDB Ouput Document](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDB+Output):
[image]

How I can to do this using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI)?

Answer (score 3):

try to add modifier options "$addToSet"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To insert into a Mongodb using PDI step MONGODB OUTPUT, the trick is in the 'Mongo Document Path' column. Put a bracket `[]` in the end of the field path where you want the array (See the `data.labels[].id` in below screenshot), and use `$set` as modifier operation.

You can also use a pointer if you want the data into a specific array. Use `[n]` at the end of field path (see the `tags[0]`, `tags[1]`, `tags[2]` in below screenshot). Note that the first array begins as 0.

[image]